# How to pass function that needs to be defined in useEffect to another component in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I have a function:

```
const onReset = ()  => {
      setElements(initialElements);
      //console.log("reset clicked");
    };
```

The problem is `initialElements` must be defined inside a `useEffect` block. Moreover, `initialElements` have specific functions that are defined in the `useEffect` block.

How do I defined a function so that I can pass `onReset` to a child component like so:

```
  <Sidebar onSave={onSave} onRestore={onRestore} onReset={onReset} setElements={setElements} removeElements = {removeElements} onDownload={onDownload} 
                onHandleChange={onHandleChange}/>
```

Comment: Why must this function be defined in useEffect? Sounds like an anti-pattern.

Comment: I'm new to react but was following the example here: https://reactflow.dev/examples/custom-node/. I had assumed it was because we needed to wait for the rest of the DOM to render but perhaps not? Some guidance would be very helpful as still learning this.

Comment: Please show the code for your entire component.

Comment: I think you're right, I got it working without useEffect. Can you let me know why it was included on the page provided? that might be easiest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it seems a simple misunderstanding of the code example you're working with in the React Flow library. As pertains to scope, specifically.

Although the example declares `onChange` in the `useEffect` method, it never attempts to call `onChange` outside the scope of `useEffect`, which is what you were attempting to do.

In the `setElements` state update, which is within the `useEffect` method, notice this object:

```
{
    id: '2',
    type: 'selectorNode',
    data: { onChange: onChange, color: initBgColor },
    style: { border: '1px solid #777', padding: 10 },
    position: { x: 300, y: 50 },
  },
```

This gets passed to the component, but `onChange` is never directly called outside `useEffect`, so it never violates any scoping rules.

Comment: But why is useEffect needed at all?

Comment: Because, they need this code to execute when the component mounts, so it can update the DOM properly.

Comment: Ah, because it's specifically updating the background color of the DOM. I see. I am not using it so it's not needed. Marking this as complete. It does beg the question though, if I wanted to "reset" and call `setElements(initialElements)` as defined in other examples how that would work?

Comment: Not only the bgcolor. React flow is doing all kinds of DOM work,  creating nodes, setting styles, the whole works. To reset to initial elements,  I'm assuming you have separate state storing the initial elements that hasn't be mutated. That being the case, your current solution should work fine. Simply call `onReset` on the preferred event.